# In hyperledger fabric, if the organization lost its client user certificate, how to resolve the client user certificate in fabric ca?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Using fabric ca, the organization registered and enrolled client user. The generated certificates are kept in the directory. Unfortunately if the generated certificates are deleted . How to recover those client user certificate?

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: `generated certificates are deleted`
do you mean wallet(+privateKey)? or just certifiacte?

Comment: After fabric-ca client enrollment, the registered user certificate are stored in the wallet. I lost that wallet.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Admin client

In the case of admin client id and pw, they are set when uploaded to fabric-ca. In this case, you can make a new request to fabric-ca through the `enroll` command.

---

#### 2. User client

In this situation, it cannot be solved through the functions provided by the fabric, but must be solved through some kind of trick.

0. Give up and create a new user ID. - Existing identities cannot be recovered.
1. Fabric-ca is initialized and newly registered. -
2. How to clean the existing registered user client of the database and register a same one - The user client id is the same, but the key and cert are newly created.
3. This is a method of artificially modifying fabric-ca's secret validation binary code, so that it unconditionally operates as true. after modifying the code, build binary or docker to operate `reenroll` normally, issue a new cert and key. and then return to the original binary.

- Of course, methods 3 and 4 are the trick, and it's right that it doesn't work.
- When a key is lost in Fabric, there is no way to reissue it.